# Storing a query in a variable is adding a space in the string in ksh

Tags: shell, unix, sqlplus, ksh

I have this variable where I want to store a query that is inside a database.

Here is the variable

```
QUERY=`sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS <<EndSQL7
      set pagesize 0
      set feedback off
      set verify off
      set heading off
      set echo off
      select query
         from generic_groupjob_table
         where process_id = '${PROCESSID}'
         and group_id = '${GROUPID}';
      EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
      EndSQL6`
```

when i echo the query, I see there is a space in the middle the string.  So when I want to use that variable in another query I get the issue saying that i'm missing terminating quote due to that space.  But that space is not supposed to be there.

```
sqlplus -s $DG_USER/$DG_PASS >> $LOGFILE <<EndSQL7
@generic_values.sql blah.txt '$QUERY'
EXIT SQL.SQLCODE 
EndSQL7
```

The query will just return 1 column of values.  What could be causing this unnecessary space?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue.  It had to do with line feeder and carraige stop.

I added a parameter set linesize xxx and it fixed the space issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try without any spaces you have for formatting purposes:

```
QUERY=`sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS <<EndSQL7
set pagesize 0
set feedback off
set verify off
set heading off
set echo off
select query
from generic_groupjob_table
where process_id = '${PROCESSID}'
and group_id = '${GROUPID}';
EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
EndSQL6`
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

QUERY=`sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS <<EndSQL7
      set pagesize 0
      set TRIM ON
      set TRIMSPOOL ON
      set feedback off
      set verify off
      set heading off
      set echo off
      select query
         from generic_groupjob_table
         where process_id = '${PROCESSID}'
         and group_id = '${GROUPID}';
      EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
      EndSQL6`